The crisis by Thomas Paine 2: Questions about the paragraph of "Tories: ... kept a tavern at Amboy..."

I once felt all that kind of anger, which a man ought to feel, against
the mean principles Q0 that are held by the Tories: a noted one, who kept
a tavern at Amboy, was standing at his door, with as pretty a child in
his hand Q1, about eight or nine years old, as I ever saw, and after
speaking his mind as freely as he thought was prudent Q2, finished with
this unfatherly expression Q3, "Well! give me peace in my day."

Q0: Why describing a noted Tory in details right after mentioning the mean principles? What's the logic connection between them?
Q1: What's the point of mention his child was pretty? How does this serve the purpose of the argument or persuade that the writer wanted to do?
Q2: What was prudent? I am asking what is the subject for "was prudent".
Q3: So 'unfatherly expression' here means a line that a father should not say?
(More questions to come later. Thanks!)


Not a man lives on the continent but fully believes that a separation
must some time or other finally take place, and a generous parent
should have said, "If there must be trouble, let it be in my day, that
my child may have peace;" and this single reflection, well applied, is
sufficient to awaken every man to duty. Not a place upon earth might
be so happy as America. Her situation is remote from all the wrangling
world, and she has nothing to do but to trade with them. A man can
distinguish himself between temper and principle, and I am as
confident, as I am that God governs the world, that America will never
be happy till she gets clear of foreign dominion. Wars, without
ceasing, will break out till that period arrives, and the continent
must in the end be conqueror; for though the flame of liberty may
sometimes cease to shine, the coal can never expire.


Can you provide a link to the document that your first quote comes from? And why the second quote?

I broke the paragraph into pieces of quotes in order to ask questions. Here is a link to the whole article: https://ushistory.org/paine/crisis/c-01.htm

Hello Max,  this is an odd text to use for learning English. Normally you should use modern texts as examples for study, as the language and the culture of that time is very different.  I'd suggest using something different.  If you are not using this text to study English (but you are studying history, using English) then [English.se] or [History.se] may be more appropriate.

Q0 and Q1 are not about English language; they depend on contextual knowledge (who the Tories were, who the man was). Thus they're off-topic.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about a 250-year old text (and context) that's completely unsuitable for non-native Anglophones who want to learn English

I’m voting to close this question because the questions  asked, though they are interesting, are not suited for this site, as they are not about the grammar or syntax but about the historical context of the passage.  The question would be better asked on https://history.stackexchange.com/

Hi guys, all my questions are about English and I think I can decide what material I can use to learn.  For example, Q0, I asked about the logic, why the writer mention the noted Tory right after the mean principles. As for Q1, I just do not understand why mentioning the noted Tory in such a detail like his Tarven and his pretty child would fit in the argument.


He is a man that Paine used as an example, identified only by his  occupation and place of residence.

He spoke as freely as he thought was prudent - i.e. to have spoken any more freely would have been imprudent.

The next part of the passage explains it. If there was peace in his day there would probably be war when his child was grown up.


